# PHP не заменяется ключ в массиве

Tags: php

Не заменяется ключ в массиве, почему?
Заранее спасибо.

```
    $names = [
    "0" => ["name" => "Андрей"],
    ];

    $replace_names = ["0" => ["name" => "Степан"]];

    $inventory = array_merge($names, $replace_names);

    echo $names["0"]["name"];
```

Выводит:
**Андрей**

Answer (score 2):

> *Не заменяется ключ в массиве, почему?*

Потому, что вы передаёте в array_merge() двумерный массив, и ещё у вас ошибка в том, что вы проверяете результат в исходном массиве, а нужно смотреть в новом:

```
$names = [
    ["name" => "Андрей"],
];

$replace_names = [
    ["name" => "Степан"]
];

$inventory = array_merge($names[0], $replace_names[0]);

echo $inventory["name"];
```