# PHP ключ в массиве не заменятся

Tags: php

Почему в первом коде "1" ключ не заменяется, а втором элемент "b" заменяется?

```
<?php

$inventory = [
    "0" => ["sku" => "81231846523248", "name" => "Spilvens", "price" => "12.99"],
    "1" => ["sku" => "84751530004684", "name" => "Pleds", "price" => "24.99"],
    "2" => ["sku" => "81474113134254", "name" => "Aizkari", "price" => "19.99"],
    "3" => ["sku" => "84554454386186", "name" => "Veļas grozs", "price" => "29.99"],
    ];

$replace_inv = ["0" => ["sku" => "81231846523248", "name" => "Spilvens HOME", "price" => "14.99"]];

$inventory = array_merge($inventory, $replace_inv);

echo $inventory["0"]["name"];
?>

<!-- Второй код -->

<br>

<?php

$a = [
"a" => ["sku" => "81231846523248", "name" => "Spilvens", "price" => "12.99"],
"b" => ["sku" => "81231846523248", "name" => "Spilvens", "price" => "12.99"]
];

$b = ["b" => ["sku" => "81231846523248", "name" => "Spilvens HOME", "price" => "14.99"]];

$a = array_merge($a, $b);

echo $a["b"]["name"];   
?>'
```

Отличие от "подобного" вопроса - он блин другой.

Comment: А на что он должен в первом примере заменяться? `$replace_inv` неиспользуемая переменная. Но думаю проблема в цифровых ключах, видимо они уже не стринги, а порядковые номера

Comment: Исправил, теперь, вроде, все верно написал.

Comment: документацию прочитайте, написано ведь, числовые ключи будут сброшены и перенумерованы, строковые заменены

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [PHP не заменяется ключ в массиве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/897332/php-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

читаем документацию к [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php)

> Если входные массивы имеют **одинаковые строковые ключи**, тогда каждое последующее значение **будет заменять** предыдущее.
> Однако, если массивы имеют **одинаковые числовые ключи**, значение, упомянутое последним, не заменит исходное значение, а будет **добавлено в конец** массива.

Напомню также, что помимо функции объединения есть и оператор объединения `+`.

> Если вы хотите дополнить первый массив элементами второго без перезаписи элементов первого массива и без переиндексации, используйте оператор объединения массивов +:
>
> Ключи из первого массива будут сохранены. **Если ключ массива существует в обоих массивах, то будет использован элемент из первого массива, а соответствующий элемент из второго массива будет проигнорирован.**

Так что поведение, которого вы  хотите добиться будет простым:

```
$inventory = $replace_inventory  + $inventory;
```